# Create model classes with openapi generator which implements external interface

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using openapi-generator to generate java classes.

I want the model classes to implement an external interface which has not been generated by openapi-generator.

Is there something that can be defined within the model yaml or a property that can be passed to the openapi-generator-maven-plugin which allows for this behaviour?

Example of required behaviour:

```
package com.example.model;

/**
 * ExampleModel
 */
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")
public class ExampleModel implements com.example.CustomInterface {
  @JsonProperty("property1")
  private String property1;

  @JsonProperty("property2")
  private String property2;
```

Answer (score 6):

Since openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 6.0.0 there is a better way: **x-implements**

Simply modify the schema-definition in your api.yml and the generated java-classes will implement the specified interfaces

```
openapi: 3.0.0
components:
  schemas:
    MyObject:
      type: object
      description: object that will implement interface
      x-implements: ['com.example.Interface']
      properties:
        data:
          description: some data
          type: object
```

(The feature existed in earlier versions but was bugged, this has been fixed: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11636)

NOTE: you must use the fully-qualified interface name, eg java.io.Serializable instead of just Serializable

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to modify all of the classes in the same way I would opt for changing the template. In your case that is most probably this file: [pojo.mustache](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/pojo.mustache)

Just copy it over to your `src/main/resources/` folder (maybe in a subfolder named custom) and adapt it according to your needs.

Then you need to adapt your `pom.xml`, too:

```
<configuration>

    <!-- The following line is crucial: -->
    <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/custom</templateDirectory>

    <!-- Your other config goes here: -->
    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
    <generatorName>java</generatorName>
    <configOptions>
        <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Also have a look at this [templating documentation](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/) for more information on the subject.